# What is the most effective method of defending a star?

Tags: sins-of-a-solar-empire

In Sins: Trinity, what is the most effective method of holding and defending a star and the associated system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred method of holding a star is to use a Starbase and a few capital ships, along with two or three repair yards. This is also an excellent way to train up capital ships preparatory to sending them out on assault missions.

Comment: i go for multiple starbases my self, loaded down with fighters.  Stars are so big that ships can take forever to reach the other side, often letting targets get away.  Fighters and bombers are much faster.

Comment: It's been a little while since I've played, but I thought you could only have one Starbase in a gravity well. Edit: Nevermind, I was thinking about planets.

Comment: for planets yes, but not for stars.  You can have multiple star bases there.